# How can I find the value of an arbitrary variable in Enclosed namespace in Python

Tags: python, namespaces

Python has several built-in functions and magic dictionaries that let me examine the value of a variable with an arbitrary name. `locals()['foo']` yields the value of the local variable named `foo`; `globals()['foo']` yields the value of that name at global scope. If I have a class instance `x`, I can look at `x.__dict__` to see the values of instance variables.

I can't seem to find any way to leverage Python's LEGB name evaluation mechanism to find the value of an arbitrarily named variable in the "closest" scope.

```
def foo(cmd: str, b: str, c=None, d=None, e=None):
    req_x = {'c', 'd'}
    req_y = {'c', 'e'}
    if cmd == 'x':
        data = {name: locals()[name] for name in req_x}
    elif cmd == 'y':
        data = {name: locals()[name] for name in req_y if locals()[name] in b}
```

This doesn't work, because `locals()` within a comprehension is scoped to that comprehension. The variables in `foo`, including parameters, are in the Enclosed scope; not Local, not Global, not Built-in. Python itself can search the enclosed scopes; the reference to `b` in the second comprehension is legal and well-defined.

What would I use in place of `locals()[name]` to get the value of a variable with that name according to LEGB search rules?

("Capture the value of `locals()` outside the comprehension and reference the copy inside the comprehension" is a useful workaround, but it's not an answer to my question.)

Comment: I don't think this is going to be easy if you want to do this dynamically. Note, the compiler actually decides ahead of time for local / enclosing variables, using special opcodes to retrieve local variables (`FAST_LOAD`) or variables in a closure,(`LOAD_DEREF`)

Comment: For example, when you say: "Python itself can search the enclosed scopes; the reference to b in the second comprehension is legal and well-defined." that isn't actually what happens. When the code for the dictionary comprehension is compiled, the reference to `b` essentially becomes a `LOAD_DEREF` which just inspects the cell/free-variable storage of the code object directly.

Comment: This is ugly, but it works for this use case. It is **not** a general solution.

```
import inspect

def foo(cmd: str, b: str, c=None, d=None, e=None):
    req_x = {'c', 'd'}
    req_y = {'c', 'e'}
    if cmd == 'x':
        data = {name: inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals[name] for name in req_x}
    elif cmd == 'y':
        data = {name: inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals[name] for name in req_y if inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals[name] in b}
```
In `{key: expr1 for var in enumerable if expr2}`, both `expr1` and `expr2` are evaluated in (distinct) nested frames.

Comment: yeah, the `frame.f_locals` might be a good enough hack. Of course, a lot of this is going to be pretty brittle. There may be cases where `f_locals` isn't created

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why it is happening, but I would guess that it is because your query is hard-coded to use `:name` as the parameter name, which is different than the one that SQLAlchemy would have chosen.
You can override the parameter name by using the `bindparam` construct:

```
@classmethod
def get_by_name(cls, name):
    sql = '''
    SELECT first_name, last_name FROM dbo.[user] WHERE username = :username
    '''
    obj = DBSession.query(cls).from_statement(text(sql)).params(
        username=name.encode()).first()
    return obj
```